# Nested quantifiers in boost::regex

Tags: c++, regex, boost

Is `\d++` a valid regular expression in programming languages that don't support possessive quantifier?Is it equivalent to `(\d+)+`?

When testing it in Python,an error `sre_constants.error: multiple repeat` will be raised.In C#,it will throw a runtime exception:`System.ArgumentException: parsing "\d++" - Nested quantifier +`.As well as boost::xpressive.
But `\d++...+` is considered valid in boost::regex.

```
wchar_t* s = L"abc123" ;
wregex e(L"\\d+++", boost::regex::normal) ;
wcmatch m ;

if(regex_search(s, m, e)){
    wcout <<  m[0] << endl ;
}
```

The output is `123`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code throws an instance of boost::bad_expression with "Invalid preceding regular expression" for me. 
Its a redhat linux system compiled with gcc 3.4.6 and boost 1_32.

Comment: I compiled it with Visual C++ 2008 and boost 1.36|1.44.

Answer (score 1):

Without possessive quantifiers, what would `\d++` (or `(\d+)+`) mean?

Let's assume it was a valid syntax, and we could read it as "one or more (one or more digit)". In that case, we'd still be able to reduce the expression to `\d+` (`\d+` matches a single digit, so `(\d+)+` could be simplified to `(\d)+`, which still matches one or more digits) . Therefore, `\d++` would be redundant.

I am not aware of any regular expression engine wither `\d++` is valid syntax, aside from engines that support possessive quantifiers.