# boost regex without possessive quantifiers

Tags: c++, regex, boost

Is there a similar way to write this regex without using possessive quantifiers (ie  ++ and *+  ?

```
boost::regex testing123("\"value\":\"((?:[^\\\"\\\\]++|\\\\.)*+)\"");
```

I think this is comparable(?):

```
boost::regex testing123("\"value\":\"(?>(?:(?>[^\\\"\\\\]+)|\\\\.)*)\"");
```

Update:  It's trying to match quoted text--but inside the double quotes, there can be a number of inner, escaped quotes.

Comment: When asking regex questions it's always nice to give a description of what you're trying to match. Just giving the regex is a bit of a pain, because we don't really know what your input and output criteria are.

Comment: I second CanSpice's request. Just tell us what it is you're trying to match, and we'll tell you what we think is/is not necessary to get it to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possessive quantifiers are just syntactic sugar for atomic grouping, i.e. `(ab)*+` is equivalent to `(?>(ab)*)`. Using this, you can rewrite your whole expression without using possessive quantifiers.

Comment: That's another question... If your regex engine allows using possessive quantifiers, there's no reason not to use them (and I'm pretty sure boost's regex allows that). :)

Comment: Boost regex works fine with possessive quantifiers in most cases, but I've run into issues using them in redhat.  Someone else mentioned having the same problem here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593838/nested-quantifiers-in-boostregex

Answer (score 1):

I've found that it is a valuable skill to know how to write regular expressions using as few bells and whistles as possible:

```
"value":"([^\"]|\.)*"
```

What this is essentially saying is:

- Match `"value":"` (the easy part)
- Match zero or more occurances of:

  - Anything other than a `\` or `"`, OR
  - Match a `\`, followed by zero or more `\`'s, followed by any non-`\` character.
- End the regex when matching the final `"`

This allows for any escape sequence, and it assumes that the backslash *always* distinguishes an escape sequence (meaning that `\\"` is not an escaped quote, but rather an escaped `\` followed by the terminating quote).

Putting it into the same syntax that you had (by escaping special characters), we get:

```
boost::regex testing123("\"value\":\"([^\\\"]|\\.)*\"");
```

Always try to keep regular expressions simple.